# Textbox type="date" functions fine in Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari

I have a textbox that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" Type="date" CssClass="form-control" Width="175" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the date" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="tbDate" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

When I run it in Chrome, the placeholder text is mm/dd/yyyy and functions as expected with the dropdown datepicker. I have set up my database to only accept the date in this format.

However in Safari, the type="date" is not recognized and it defaults to a normal textbox. Even if the date typed in is 05/20/2015, it still causes an error.

Any suggestions to either fix this or get around it?

Comment: What version of Safari you're testing on?

Comment: thats going to be an issue of browser implementation and its going to be pretty different across various browsers, versions of those browsers etc. This is why utilities that provide polyfills are prefered. I'm sure you can find something in bootstrap that will give you the same behavior in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Older versions of Safari provide date-formatted text fields, but no real calendar widget.